# URL rewrite procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have site name like http://www.abcd.com and in the site i have propertydetails page.
So now i want to display in url  http://www.abcd.com/hy2345 instead of  http://www.abcd.com?propertydetails.aspx?id=hy2345

Here another problem is if the user will enter directly  http://www.abcd.com/hy2345 so automatically redirect to propertydetails page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there was a very similar post this lunch time (GMT) that mentioned a library that did it... ill see if i can find it :)

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0/60861#60861

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MVC?  If so, you can configure this behavior in the global.asax file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have tried but i didnt get

Answer (score 1):

The [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) tool makes this really easy. They have an [example](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) that is almost identical to the rule you would need to create.

Here is how you might do it.  The way you requested makes it tricky because it would try to route every request, so this one will match every url that is like www.abcd.com/properties/hy2345 but you could easily match the hy2345 with a custom regex depending on your id naming business logic.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^properties/([_0-9a-z-]+)/" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="propertydetails.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

For IIS6, this is a bit trickier.  [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) has a post with your options (see section entitled Approach 4). Another option is looking at [UrlRewriter.net](https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter) or [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: this method requires the .aspx extension**

I recently did this and it was suprisingly very easy to do.

In my App_Data folder I have a xml file like the folowing:

```
<urlrewrites> 
  <rewrite url="/hy2345.aspx" to="~/propertydetails.aspx?id=hy2345" />
  <rewrite url="/hy2346.aspx" to="~/propertydetails.aspx?id=hy2346" />
</urlrewrites>
```

And in my global.asax this quick routine:

```
void Application_Beginrequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Context.Request.Path);
            if (ext != ".aspx")
            {
                return;
            }

            string root = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            string fullOriginalPath = Request.Url.ToString();
            string relativePath = fullOriginalPath.Replace(root, "");

            System.Xml.XmlDocument objXML = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            objXML.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/URLRewrites.xml"));

            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in objXML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name.ToLower() == "rewrite")
                {
                    string url = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("url").Value.ToString();
                    if (relativePath.ToLower() == url.ToLower())
                    {
                        string to = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("to").Value.ToString();
                        Context.RewritePath(to);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If your page is handling postbacks you will need to implement the form browser yadda from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) as a post back will expose the unwritten url.